# member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Tags: asp.net

when i try to run an web application in visual studio 2008.. i got this error...

> 'PopupWindow': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

also while correcting errors my startup web page changed..dont know how to setback the original startup webpage...

```
public partial class PopupWindow {
    /// <summary>
    /// frmPopupWindow control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm frmPopupWindow;
    /// <summary>
    /// PopupWindow1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::Sdi.Pss.WebControls.Control PopupWindow;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got a field called `PopupWindow` in a class called `PopupWindow`. Just don't do that. Change the name of the field to something else.

Quite why this affected your startup web page I don't know... normally I just hit F5 when I've got the page I want highlighted :) You can specify it in the "Web" part of your project properties though.