# Bypassing member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, dynamics-crm-2011, odata

Similar to: [member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528786/member-names-cannot-be-the-same-as-their-enclosing-type) except I can't change the metadata, I want to just ignore the class entirely.

I am trying to add a Service Reference in Visual Studio 2010 but I get the following error.

> The custom tool ‘DataServiceClientGenerator’ failed. Data service
>   client code-generation failed: Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>   (0,0) : error 0042: Name foo cannot be used in type
>   Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.foo. Member names cannot be the
>   same as their enclosing type..

I understand that this error is because someone named a field `foo` in the object `foo` but I can't change that..

so without being able to make any changes within CRM, how can I generate my service reference?

I have thought of downloading the `$metadata` and then removing the offending type and then saving it (as the type is not one that I will be using anyway). But I do not know how to get this to work because it's not overly straight forward.

I have tried making the service reference with both C# and VB.NET and neither worked, ideally it would be a solution that works for both, but at this point I would be open to a solution that only works for one of these.

Comment: there is actually a member field named foo  in Microsoft solutions?  LOLs :-)

Comment: @TomerW no, our CRM solution was customized and includes some additional classes and `foo` represents a class that has a `foo` field. As per http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3092 `foo` is used as a metasyntactic variable without any proper explanation or definition, commonly when the actual meaning of the variable is meaningless to the scope of context.

Comment: ya, i know about foo bar,
I didn't think you change the Exception message :)

Comment: @TomerW That seems an odd assumption, the actual error message contained a client company's name as part of the field hence I removed this content and substituted with `foo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have worked out how to resolve this issue.

```
http://localhost/myWcfDataService.svc/$metadata
```

Save this result to disk such as `c:\metadata.csdl`

Then manually edit the file and remove (or rename) the offending field (this will result in it not being usable in your service, but it is better than the whole service not working).

Then run the following:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\DataSvcUtil.exe /language:CSharp /in:c:\metadata.csdl /out:c:\serviceReference1.cs
```

Now add the newly generated `serviceReference1.cs` file to your visual studio project, look for the class that inherits from `System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext` this is your service entry point.

Further information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756369.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Seph, i came up with somewhat improved way to add actual reference, not simple .cs file:

- Save your `http://localhost/myWcfDataService.svc/$metadata` as file, eg. `myService.csdl`
- Edit it to solve `names cannot be the same as their enclosing type` manually. It is caused when a class has a field with the same name. I decided to rename classes, eg. from `foo` to `foo_`. You can rename fields instead. Run `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\DataSvcUtil.exe /language:CSharp /in:myService.csdl /out:serviceReference1.cs` periodically to see when you eliminated all errors.
- Rename `myService.csdl` to `$metadata`
- Temporarily run some web-server in the same folder as `$metadata` file. For example, i had python 3 installed and simply ran `python -m http.server` from the folder where `$metadata` is.
- Add Service Reference in Visual Studio as usual, but use your temporary webserver address. In my case it was `http://localhost:8000`. Visual Studio will request `/$metadata` and generate everything.